# Why won't the updated Node.js version be used in my project?

Tags: node.js, terminal

I want to use the latest version of `Node.js` in my `React Native` project but I'm running into some errors.  I can't see how all of this is happening even though I followed the instructions. How would I go about fixing this?

Upon running `brew install node` I get this error:

```
Warning: node 8.2.1 is already installed, it's just not linked.
You can use `brew link node` to link this version.
```

Fair. So now I ran `brew link node` like it said, I get this error:

```
Error: Could not symlink bin/node
Target /usr/local/bin/node
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/node'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite node

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run node
```

Fair again.  So I ran `brew link --overwrite node`, I get this error:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/8.2.1... 
Error: Could not symlink share/doc/node/gdbinit
/usr/local/share/doc/node is not writable.
```

Comment: This looks like an issue with permissions, what does `ls -l /usr/local/share/doc/node` say? Also, if you switch node versions often, I recommend you use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

Comment: It's not writable because you don't have permission to write to it. It is obviously writable because it's on disk. Just run the `brew link` command under `sudo`